# Как в JS реализовать клик с помощью addEventListener

Tags: javascript

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.row div')
for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener('click', divpress)
}

function divpress() {
  divs.innerHTML = Math.random()
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 12%
}

.row div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  text-align: center
}

.btns {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Есть 25 `DIV`. При клике на одном, внутри нужно вывести случайное число.

Не понимаю, в чём у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы создаете массив, а затем делаете цикл с повторением равным количеству элементов массива.

Вместо этого лучше перебирать массив через `forEach()` и к каждому элементу массива добавлять `eventListner`.

Можно и вашим способом, ошибки в этом нет. Но `forEach()` "привычнее" что-ли.

Ошибка в самой функции. Вместо вот этого `divs.innerHTML = Math.random()` для того, чтобы положить случайное число внутрь div нужно обращаться к диву на который кликнули через `this`

### Вот так:

```js
let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.row div');
divs.forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener('click', divpress)
})

function divpress() {
  this.innerHTML = Math.random()
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-left: 12%
}

.row div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: burlywood;
  text-align: center
}

.btns {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="btns">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: а как можно, при повторном нажатии на DIV увеличить число на 1?

Comment: If (this.innerHtml == "") {this.innerHTML = Math.random()} else {this.innerHTML += 1}

Comment: спасибо большое